# Assigning 2D list to 2 Dataframe columns Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have tried the following and got error:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[2,2]])
>>> df
   0  1
0  0  0
1  2  2
>>> y = [[0,0],[2,2],[3,3]]
>>> df["s","d"] = y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3119, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3194, in _set_item
    value = self._sanitize_column(key, value)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3391, in _sanitize_column
    value = _sanitize_index(value, self.index, copy=False)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 4001, in _sanitize_index
    raise ValueError('Length of values does not match length of ' 'index')
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
>>> df[["s","d"]] = y
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3116, in __setitem__
    self._setitem_array(key, value)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3142, in _setitem_array
    indexer = self.loc._convert_to_indexer(key, axis=1)
  File "C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1327, in _convert_to_indexer
    .format(mask=objarr[mask]))
KeyError: "['s' 'd'] not in index"
```

Let me know how i can create 2 columns with 2D array simultaneously.

Comment: I am trying to add new column sir. This will replace my previous column names.

Comment: You see i have already created the `df`, I am not creating new df but adding two columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` constructor and assign to nested lists:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[2,2]])

y = [[0,0],[2,2]]

df[["s","d"]] = pd.DataFrame(y)
print (df)
   0  1  s  d
0  0  0  0  0
1  2  2  2  2
```

Another solution is create new `DataFrame` and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['s','d'], index=df.index))
```

If you want add multiple columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[2,2]])

y = [[0,0],[2,2],[3,3]]

df[["s","d","e"]] = pd.DataFrame(np.array(y).T)
print (df)
   0  1  s  d  e
0  0  0  0  2  3
1  2  2  0  2  3

z = [[0,0,3],[2,2,3]]
df[["s","d","e"]] = pd.DataFrame(z)
print (df)
   0  1  s  d  e
0  0  0  0  0  3
1  2  2  2  2  3
```

If need append 2 new columns to 3 rows DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[2,2],[4,4]])

y = [[0,0],[2,2],[3,3]]

df[["s","d"]] = pd.DataFrame(y)
print (df)

   0  1  s  d
0  0  0  0  0
1  2  2  2  2
2  4  4  3  3
```

else get missing values:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[2,2]])

y = [[0,0],[2,2],[3,3]]

df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(y, columns=['s','d']), how='outer')
print (df)
     0    1  s  d
0  0.0  0.0  0  0
1  2.0  2.0  2  2
2  NaN  NaN  3  3
```

Comment: this is actually really good, if you add how='outer' to the join you should be able to extend the index as well - is that right @jezrael?

Comment: @Stael - hmm, what is reason for outer join? I think need left join, default of `join`

Comment: i understood the question that he was trying to add 2 columns of length 3, not 3 columns of length 2. @JafferWilson which is it?

Comment: @Stael - yes, it is a bit unclear, so added some solutions for append original list

Comment: guess for the I need to have equal values in the existing dataframe... :P

Comment: @Stael - I understand now, added to answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can't do this directly as you're trying, but this is a bit of a work around:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[0,0],[2,2]])

y = [[0,0],[2,2]]


df["s"], df["d"] = [i[0] for i in y], [i[1] for i in y]
```

you have a few problems, one of which is that `df['s', 'd']` isn't correct indexing, you need `df[['s', 'd']]` - but you also can't assign from lists directly to that.

you also can't assign anything longer than the index, so your `y = [[0,0],[2,2],[3,3]]` is too long.